# gitlab pipeline on sub projects

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Suppose main project has sub-projects

```
MainProject/
       \-------- android
                   \-------- .gitlab-ci-android.yml
       \-------- ios
       \-------- lib
       \-------- .gitlab-ci.yml
```

I want my **.gitlab-ci.yml** to run parallel jobs for each subfolder. My goal is to have separate **.gitlab-ci.yml** files. Yes, it looks messy to touch only one file when you have to configure the CI of a few projects.

What is the exact command line to run jobs from the main **.gitlab-ci.yml**?

I tried with , but not working

```
jobAndroid:
  script: "gitlab-runner exec android/.gitlab-ci-android.yml"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [include:local](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#includelocal) syntax for this. Include the CI files from your subfolders in your main `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
include:
  - local: '/android/.gitlab-ci-android.yml'
```

Comment: Thank you. 
But I get a syntax error ```jobs:include config should be a hash``` with GitLab Community Edition 11.1.1 94b9323

Comment: Ah, you'll need to update your GitLab instance. For the original include syntax on GitLab CE, you'll need GitLab 11.4 or later. And, the newer `include:local` syntax requires GitLab 11.7 or later.